# Save value in Javascript variable from $.get and use it in PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I am getting some basic info of the visitor on my site using javascript.

```
var userinfo = "";
//printing user info
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
  alert("IP: " + response.ip);
  alert("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
  alert(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
  userinfo = (JSON.stringify(response,null,4)); //saving json in js variable (not working, it says undefined)
}, "jsonp");
```

Then I want to access this value in my PHP variable:

```
 <?php
echo $getuserinfo ; // How to store JS var here in this php var?
 ?>
```

The JS variable value is not being saved, what I am doing wrong?
And how can I store JS variable value in PHP variable?

Comment: `javascript` will run on `client-side` & `php` will run on `server-side`, how do you supposed to do that?

Comment: @sgt There must be definitely a way to access the javascript variable in my php varaible. Since all of the code is in the same 1 file.
Can you help me in saving the response value in JS variable?

Comment: you cannot use php variable on the client side. Rather find out a way to do with js only.

Comment: php will be availabe before the page load so you can not assign any javascript variable to php but the reverse is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using the PHP version of the API:

```
  function ip_details($ip) {
   $json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
   $details = json_decode($json);
   //echo $ip;
   return $details;
   }
  $details = ip_details($userIp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a stat page/api that you make a ajax call to from javascript.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: '/setstats.php',
 data: {userdata: userinfo},
 success: function(){
  console.log("Userdata send");
 },
 dataType: "json"
});
```

This will first be avalible at a later time then when the page initally loads, but you could now have it saved in the session for the next requests.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `jQuery.get` method.

This method support a parameter called Data

```
data
Type: PlainObject or String
A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
```

After it is sent to the server to `http://ipinfo.io` it is available in the called script (index.php or what you have as default) in the `$_GET` array.

If you send `data: {var1: value1, var2: value2}` you will have `$_GET["var1"] and $_GET["var2"]`

Simply send `data: userinfo` and in php do a `var_dump($_GET)` and check what you got